# SQL join a table with an indirect foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, adventureworks

I am trying to select 2 columns from 3 tables that are indirectly linked

dbo.Person

| BusinessID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Haley Keller |
| 002 | Ceila Mark |

EmployeeDepartmentHistory

| BusinessID | DeptID |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 201 |
| 002 | 104 |

HumanResources.Department

| DeptID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 104 | Accounting |
| 201 | Sales |

I tried;

```sql
SELECT P.Name AS NAME, E.DeptID AS DEPARTMENT
FROM dbo.Person P
JOIN HumanResources.Department E ON E.DeptID = (SELECT
B.DeptID FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory B
WHERE P.BusinessID IN (SELECT BusinessID FROM
dbo.Person))
```

But it just displays an empty table view with the columns NAME | DEPARTMENT

Comment: `WHERE P.BusinessID IN (SELECT BusinessID FROM
dbo.Person))` doesn't make sense. The only time this would not be TRUE is if `BusinessID` had the value `NULL`, otherwise a value will *always* be in a list that includes itself.

Comment: Please try this and see if it works:                                                                                          SELECT P.Name as [Name], E.DeptID as [DEPARTMENT] 
FROM dbo.Person P
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory B
 JOIN HumanResources.Department E ON (E.DeptID = B.DeptID)
ON (P.BusinessID = B.BusinessID)

Comment: `= (select ` is a little risky. You can use `IN` instead of `=`, to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You only get one `FROM` clause per statement, but you can have as many `JOIN` clauses as you wish inside of it to establish the relationships between tables used in your SELECT.

```
SELECT P.Name AS NAME, E.DeptID AS DEPARTMENT
FROM dbo.Person P
    JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory B
       ON P.BusinessID = B.BusinessID
    JOIN HumanResources.Department E 
        ON B.DeptID = E.DeptId
```